# How to get file path from File object observer in v-file-input Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, filepath

I am building feature upload image with Vuetify. I need preview image before upload to server

**In v-input-file**

```
<v-file-input
  accept="image/*"
  multiple
  label="Add your files"
  chips
  filled
  prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
  @change="onAddFiles"
></v-file-input>
```

**In method change**

```
onAddFiles(files) {
  console.log(files);
}
```

[image]

You can see there is no information `file path` in `File object observer` array

I don't know how to get `file path` from this `File object observer`. Please help me and i'm so grateful!

Comment: I am not sure you can get the file path there are security issues with that.

Comment: hi Michael, i just want to get local `file path` for display image file added via v-file-input

Comment: That's what I think you cannot do, you are asking for a file path on a computer that is not yours.

Comment: No, image file is from my computer

Comment: yes but presumably you will be running the app not only on your computer, the file watcher looks for the files on the computer it is run not only your computer, it does not know who's computer it is.

Comment: you don't NEED the path of the file on the clients computer to generate a preview

Comment: How to make preview image without need `path file`?

Comment: Jaromanda X has provided the solution with base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in data, include the following

```
previews: [],
errorImage: "url of an image to use to indicate an error",
```

obviously you need to set `errorImage` to something useful

Then add some code to `onAddFiles` to generate an array of previews

```
onAddFiles(files) {
    this.previews = [];
    files.forEach((file, index) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener('load', e => this.previews[index] = e.target.result);
        reader.addEventListener('error', e => this.previews[index] = this.errorImage);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

In your markup - wherever you want you previews shown, something like

```
<span v-for="src in previews">
    <img v-if="src && src.length" :src="src"/>
</span>
```

Comment: hi Jaromanda X, this way is to parse the image to base64, right?

Comment: yes, this produces a `data:image/xxx;base64,.......` data URL

Comment: yes, i think this way is good, but is there any way to get `file path` local of image?

Comment: i think display image by file path is better

Comment: however if there is no way to get `file path`, then maybe i think i use your way :D

Comment: `i think display image by file path is better` - but, as you've been told, the browser has NO ACCESS to the file path for security reasons

Comment: yes, i understand, i tried your way and it work good for me. Thank you for your enthusiastic assistance